# How do you disable "ducking" in Android?

Tags: android, audio, soundpool

I have an Android game that plays some sound effects when users interact with it. Some of my users are complaining that while they are playing audio books or music my app will lower the volume of the background music or book. The app uses SoundPool to play in game sound effects. However the issue exists even when sound if off. In a test version of the app I even skipped the initialization of SoundPool and it had no effect. I'm not sure even where to look for this issue. I have read this article but it was no real help. https://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html

How do I make my app surrender all rights to sound and allow background apps to play at full volume?

```
// Create java sound pool
    // Check if we're running on Android 5.0 or higher
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        //Load soundpool
        AudioAttributes attrs = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .build();
        javaSoundPool = new SoundPool.Builder()
                .setMaxStreams(10)
                .setAudioAttributes(attrs)
                .build();
    } else {
        //Load pre lollipop sound pool
        javaSoundPool = new SoundPool(2, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    }

private void playJavaSoundPool(final SoundData soundData) {
    final int soundPoolId;
    //Random find the real map
    if(soundData.soundId == RANDOM_WINNER){
        final int mapId = randomWinnerSound();
        soundPoolId = soundMap.get(mapId).soundPoolId;
    } else {
        soundPoolId = soundData.soundPoolId;
    }
    // Set volume
    float streamVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    streamVolume = streamVolume / audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    // Play sound
    javaSoundPool.play(soundPoolId, streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, 1.0f);
}
```

Comment: I assume your app does not modify the sound level?

Comment: @JoxTraex My app doesn't modify the sound levels.

Comment: Hmm perhaps you should post a snippet of your sound playing code